# Create a table using existing data via VBA, using the CURRENTREGION function

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm 90% of the way into creating my first big macro project. Thanks for all your help so far everyone! I've come up against an issue however - which I think should be the last issue I should face before putting the macro into use.

I've written a macro which copies the data presented in a master spreadsheet, creates a new workbook in the target location, then creates a table using the information provided.

What I want to do is use `CurrentRegion` to allow the data to alter month-to-month. I think the code should go something like this

```
`GeneratePivotTables Macro

'Converts information stored on sheet "Data" to a table

Dim TABLE As Range

Set TABLE = Sheets("Data").A1.CurrentRegion

Sheets("Data").Listobjects.Add(x1SrcRange, Range("TABLE"), ,1Xyes).Name="Data"
```

I know this as presented is incorrect, but I'd like some help just parsing this correctly! My aim is to then be able to use the table "Data" to create pivot tables.

Comment: what is the A1 doing after Sheets("data")? did you mean sheets("data").Range("A1")?

Comment: Yep, that fixed that bit of the code! it's saying the next bit `Sheets("Data").Listobjects.Add(x1SrcRange, Range("TABLE"), ,1Xyes).Name="Data"` is invalid syntax - which i know, but i want to know how to correct it!

Comment: replace the range("Table") with just TABLE, thats the first thing noticed so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code converts the `CurrentRegion` around cell `A1` into a table. See if you can modify it for your needs.

```
Sub ConvertRangetoTable()
    Dim rngTable As Range

    Set rngTable = Sheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Sheets("Data").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable, , xlYes).Name = "All_Data"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is pretty much exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be sufficient

```
Sub M_snb()
    Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(1, [A1].CurrentRegion, , 1).Name = "snb_001"
End Sub
```